# What Do All of the Input and Output Audio Devices Mean?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, audacity

I'm running Audacity on Xubuntu and notice a lot of options for my playback and recording devices. This is surprising, given that I'm coming from Windows where there are only a couple of options (one input for my microphone and two outputs for my internal speakers and external speakers). I don't have anything except my internal laptop speakers and microphone and a set of headphones plugged in.

So here are my input (recording) options:

[Input Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xI5V.jpg)

```
HDA Intel PCH: ALC3246 Analog (hw:0,0)
sysdefault
pulse: Headphone Mic:0
pulse: Headset Mic:0
pulse: Internal Mic:0
default: Headphone Mic:0
default: Headset Mic:0
default: Internal Mic:0
```

And here are my output options:

[Output Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulATl.jpg)

```
HDA Intel PCH: HDMI 0 (hw:0,3)
HDA Intel PCH: HDMI 0 (hw:0,7)
HDA Intel PCH: HDMI 0 (hw:0,8)
HDA Intel PCH: HDMI 0 (hw:0,9)
HDA Intel PCH: HDMI 0 (hw:0,10)
hdmi
pulse
default
```

I was just wondering if somebody would be kind enough to explain to me what all of these options mean.

Comment: When you have PulseAudio, you probably want to use that.

Comment: Sure, but I'd still like to know what the other options mean just for my own knowledge.